# USB Foot Pedal MP3 files and Application Focus

Tags: transcription

Am trying to use a USB foot pedal with an XP based system to play/pause .mp3 files. The pedal has the capability of learning any key combination or sending a string per press. We've experimented with Windows Media Player which will stop/start by issuing a "space" bar input; however, the issue is the user is working with Microsoft Word to transcribe, and when she is typing Word is in focus. Ideally whatever command that the USB triggers would also put the Media Player into focus as well. It's almost as if there needs to be another macro type program involved that would be smart enough to find the Windows Media Player window, and the stop and start it on key press...

BTW, the user is not married to Windows Media player...

Comment: You can, and they have made AHK scripts that hop between windows, that would simply drive me crasy, when I would know that a single program could easily play an audio, and allow for text entry via the same window. They also have software/driver stuff that doesnt require "focus" to get the commands to it.  Check out some of the "baitware" for transcribing  http://www.audiotranskription.de/english/home and express scribe.  If you gotta swap focus , it would be 20 times better to just use a seperate Hardware digital audio device. Anything less I wouldnt make it past the first 15 minutes :-)

Answer (score 1):

I tried out [Auto Hot Key](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and was able to develop a macro that did what I described; however, I concur with Psycogeek's conclusions regarding [F4](http://www.audiotranskription.de/english/f4.htm), the transcription environment available from the Audiotranskription folks referred to in his comment. Having the audio player and transcription editor as part of the same environment is really the right way to do this.